# Is there any commands i put in the core that will suggest my account is from early days

Tags: transactions

Have you got anything i could put in the core that will point back towards or leave a clue to age of my account ,ie getdesendant/ansestors, mininginfo,or blockinfo, will any of these commands tell me anything about my account?

Comment: You can open the console (Window | Console, or Ctrl-T) and use the `listtransactions` command with "*" as the label, 10 (or whatever) as count, and keep running it with higher values for "skip" until you get the last transaction, and look up when it happened.  This only tells you the date/time of the first bitcoin you received.  Feel free to use this to answer your own question.  How old a bitcoin-core account is seems like a good question, so I vote to keep this open.

Answer (score 0):

As I've already told you in another question: no, the only way to get access to an old wallet in Bitcoin Core is having a copy/backup of your wallet.dat file.

Comment: ok cheers ,bit rusty on this stuff now used to be good back in my younger years,lol

Comment: Got it found out whats been going on and what happened wont say now need bit more time space but got a bit of work to do still, most prob be back in touch for info on segwit, also p2wpkh ,and base58 as was reading some code lastnight and very intrested on learning bit more.